# Uniformally most powerful test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, distributions, density-function, neyman-pearson-lemma

let x be a random variable with density function

f(x)= $\frac{2\theta x + 1}{\theta + 1}$ if $0\le x \le 1$,$\theta$ > -1 and 0 otherwise

consider the problem of testing   $H0 :\theta  \le 1  $ $ $ $ against  $ $H1:$ $\theta >1 $

let $\phi$ be the test function given by 
$\phi(x)$ = 1 if x $\ge$ $\frac{\sqrt{9-8\alpha}\ -1}{2}$ and 0 otherwise
then we have to prove that $\phi$ is UMP size $\alpha $  test

what i tried :

first i checked the monotone likelihood ratio and infered that UMP will exist ,.,., till then it was OK

now
for $\phi$ to be  UMP size $\alpha $  test we must have E ( $\phi$(x) ) under H0 = $\alpha$

[rest is shown in the image]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQwAI.jpg)

after this i am stuck , i have rechecked my integration it seems to be correct any suggestions / corrections please

Comment: Could you please learn mathjax and replace the scanned formulas with typed formulas, that is, with $\LaTeX$?

Comment: Although I agree with @kjetilbhalvorsen, for the sake of our vision impaired users, your handwriting is very beautiful!

Comment: Since this looks like homework add the self study tag.

Comment: You haven't yet used the hypothesis, which suggests plugging in $\theta=1$.  The integration isn't quite correct: double-check the signs and the constant term in the numerator.

Comment: 2. @ Matthew Drury , thanks very much , thats why i posted the image coz i can write clearly , but i apologize for not being good at english grammar .